# Bicep/ARM Creating storage account with endpoint link to existing DNS zone with A record created

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-bicep

I am currently trying to create a Bicep template that will deploy a storage account limiting it to the appropriate existing vnet as well as deploying a private endpoint and linking that to our **existing** Private DNS Zone in a different subscription and also creating the A record. Currently the template will deploy the storage account to the appropriate vnet and deploy a new private endpoint but I am stuck on how to get it to link to an existing private dns zone and create the A record. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
resource stg 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2020-08-01-preview' = {
  name: name
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: storageSku
  }
  kind: 'StorageV2'
  properties: {
    minimumTlsVersion: 'TLS1_2'
    allowBlobPublicAccess: true
    networkAcls: {
      bypass: 'AzureServices'
      virtualNetworkRules: [
        {
          id: '${}'
          action: 'Allow'
        }
      ]
      ipRules: []
      defaultAction: 'Deny'
    }
  }
}
resource privateEndpointName_resource 'Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints@2019-04-01'  = {
  name: privateEndpointName
  location: location
  properties: {
    privateLinkServiceConnections: [
      {
        name: privateEndpointName
        properties: {
         
          privateLinkServiceId: resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', stg.name)
          groupIds: [
            groupId
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
    
    manualPrivateLinkServiceConnections: []
    subnet: {
      
      id: '${}'
    }
  }
}

resource privateDNSZone_name 'Microsoft.Network/privateDnsZones@2018-09-01' existing  = {
  scope: resourceGroup(,  )
  name: privateDNSZone_name_var

 
}

resource privateDNSZone_name_vnetName_link 'Microsoft.Network/privateDnsZones/virtualNetworkLinks@2018-09-01' existing = {
  scope: resourceGroup(,  )
  name: '${}'
}

resource privateEndpointName_default 'Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints/privateDnsZoneGroups@2020-03-01' existing = {
  name: '${privateEndpointName_resource.name}/default'
  
}
```

Comment: Could you please tell me if the two subscriptions are in the different tenant?

Comment: Hi, hope all is well. They are in the same tenant.

Answer (score 5):

Here’s an example with sqlserver privatelink, but for storage should be similar:

```
resource privateEndpoint 'Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints@2020-06-01' = {
  name: '${sqlServer.name}-plink'
  location: location
  properties: {
    subnet: {
      id: privateLinkSnetId
    }
    privateLinkServiceConnections: [
      {
        name: '${sqlServer.name}-plink'
        properties: {
          privateLinkServiceId: sqlServer.id
          groupIds: [
            'sqlServer'
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

resource privateDNSZoneGroup 'Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints/privateDnsZoneGroups@2020-06-01' = {
  name: '${privateEndpoint.name}/default'
  properties: {
    privateDnsZoneConfigs: [
      {
        name: 'privatelink-database-windows-net'
        properties: {
          privateDnsZoneId: privateLinkDnsZoneId
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

However have in mind that there’s no link to Storage Account - each service: blob, queue, table, files has it’s own link.

The A record should be created automatically when you link private endpoint to the dns zone.

However, if you want do to a cross-resource group or cross-subscription deployments, you need to use a module - you cannot deploy resources in to different scopes within one file (module), but you can make that resource group deployment create another deployment into different resource group in this same or different subscription.

Comment: Thanks @Miq - this is super-useful. Do you have an example of what the `privateLinkDnsZoneId` in your example refers to?

Comment: @Dan it’s a resource I’d of a private dns zone, attached to the network where you create private endpoint. That zone has to have name privatelink.database.windows.net (for sql server private endpoint).